# How to use angular-notify module in angular 1.4.8?

Tags: angularjs, notifications

We are using angular 1.4.8 and I want to use the [angular-notifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-notifier) module in our application. I didn't find any valid examples that explain to me how to use it.

According to [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-notifier#angular-versions) I am not sure if I use the latest version then it will work or not.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: From the npm page you can see that the lib "angular-notifier" is not compatible with AngularJS v.1.4.8. Maybe you can try "angular-toastr", it is similar to "angular-notifier".

Comment: @aUXcoder I tried `angular-toastr` and `angular-toaster`. But i am not able to use it in my angular directive. It saying `Unknown provider: toasterProvider <- toaster <- customDirective`. Any help?